# Unable to find version '5.0.0.0' of package 'entity framework'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to install Entity Framework for MVC application.But I am getting following error:
Install-Package : Unable to find version '5.0.0.0' of package 'entityframework'

Comment: Do you have an internet access? I used to have the same problem because of my proxy configuration (to fix it I usually restart Visual Studio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was struck with the same issue and the below steps resolved the problem

Right click on the Project which throws the Nuget error
Select Manage NuGet Packages..
Click on Settings button in the bottom left corner
Under Available package sources,Select the checkbox nuget.org
Click on OK.

Now the packages will be automatically downloaded from the site.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the package by right-clicking on the project in visual studio -> 'Manage NuGet Packages' and search for EntityFramework.

Comment: How can you install an old version of a package with Visual Studio + NuGet user interface?

Comment: You could install the latest version, then open the .csproj file with a text editor, search for "Reference Include="EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0 ... " and replace "Version" with the one that you want. It would be easier to install it directly from the console, but if you are getting an error that way, it is worth a try.

Comment: Ah, ok, so you still need to do something "by hands". I search yesterday for this feature in VS2015 and I can't find it. It happens rarely to me to retrieve an old version but every time I have problems.

Comment: Well, yeah. An easy way would be if you already have installed a specific version in one of your solution projects. That way, you could go to Manage NuGet Packages for solution and select the project you want to add the package to. But apart from that, I do it "by hands" too.

Comment: If I try to search the EntityFramework,it keeps on searching.Searching was taking more then an hour,so i stopped searching.

Answer (score 0):

Entity framework 5 is uploaded without the latest 0 on the version.

This should work

```
Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 5.0.0
```

For other versions look here

http://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/

Comment: Still it gives same error:Install-Package : Unable to find version '5.0.0' of package 'entityframework'.
At line:1 char:16
+ install-package <<<<  entityframework -version 5.0.0
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

Answer (score 0):

It Worked .I went to http://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework and then installed NuGet using Visual Studio Extension Manager and then in the console window I gave command Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 5.0.0 and it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue. When i checked my proxy and made sure that internet connection is fine and has a reach over NuGet links, restarting VS later solved my problem.